# ErrorException: Array to string conversion in file

Tags: laravel

I have a problem when updating the URLImg data when I use the PUT method, it throws the following error in Postman 'ErrorException: Array to string conversion in file' but if I use the POST method I have no problem uploading the urls of my images.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $values = $request->except('URLImg');
        $data = $request->only('URLImg[]');
        if($request->hasFile('URLImg')){
            foreach($request->file("URLImg") as $image)
            {
                $name = Str::random(10).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = 'storage/img/';
                $image->move($path, $name);
                $data[] = $name;
         
                $tramite = Tramite::create($values);
                $tramite->URLImg = json_encode($data);
                $tramite->save();
            }
        }else{
            $tramite = Tramite::create($values);
            $tramite->save();
        }

        return response()->json($tramite, 201);

public function update(Request $request, Tramite $tramite)
    {
        $data = $request->only('URLImg[]');
        if($request->hasFile('URLImg')){
            foreach($request->file("URLImg") as $image)
            {
                $name = Str::random(10).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = 'storage/img/';
                $image->move($path, $name);
                $data[] = $name;
         
                $tramite->URLImg = json_encode($data);
                $tramite->save();
            }
        }

        return response()->json($tramite, 201);
    }
```

[Postman Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upuo5.jpg)
[Postman Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ1tr.jpg)

Yes, it is almost the same code but I only need to update the URLImg field

Comment: Your error message also tells you exactly which line of code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Want to use a PUT or PATCH request for form containing file uploads - submit a POST request with method spoofing

```html
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')

    ...
</form>
```

via any javascript framework like vue

```js
let data = new FormData;
data.append("_method", "PUT")

axios.post("some/url", data)
```

Using `_method` and setting it to 'PUT' or 'PATCH' will allow to declare route as a PUT route and still use POST request to submit form data

`$_FILES` will not be populated on a PUT or PATCH request with multipart/form-data - PHP limitation